# What does mean? "Are you on any sort of medication?"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I'm an English learner. I faced with a sentence that I don't meaning it.

Here is the question I don't understand but I see its answer.

> Question: Are you on any sort of medication?
>
> Answer: I need a sick note.

https://7esl.com/answers-to-common-english-questions/

So, I don't know Question meaning.

Please help.

Comment: Have you checked the meaning of the word "Medication" in a dictionary?

Comment: Also you say "I am faced with..."  Where did you read or hear this sentence.?  Is it in an English textbook?

Comment: From here https://7esl.com/answers-to-common-english-questions/

Answer (score 1):

The doctor wants to know if the person is currently taking any medications, like antibiotics, or antidepressants, etc. Some medications can interact in undesirable ways, so the doctor needs to know what medications you're taking now to make sure he doesn't prescribe anything dangerous.

The response doesn't answer the question in any way, and it reads as though the patient is just completely ignoring the doctor. The doctor wants to know what medication the patient is taking. The patient doesn't answer that, but just states what they want from the doctor. As a conversation, the exchange doesn't make any sense - it's like if I asked "Did you go to the store?" and you responded, "I want a sandwich."

Answer (score 1):

"Medication" means medicine, drugs, pills, etc. To be "on medication" means to have just taken some medicine or to be regularly taking it. Like if someone was acting strangely, you might ask, "Are you on medication?" Or a doctor might ask a patient if he is taking medicine for some illness, so he knows what has already been tried, or so that he consider whether some medicine he is considering prescribing might interact with medicine the patient is already taking.

As @NuclearHoagie says, the "answer" does not answer the question.